# C# use PsExec - No answer

Tags: c#, .net, psexec

Execute following Statement direct from a prompt

```
\\my_ip -u my_user -p my_pass -w C:\ta33 tasklist
```

returns the expected tasklist.
But using the same statement in C# Code like

```
string executeCommand = "\\\\10.141.86.30 -u biebls -p 1krahsavs -w C:\\ta33 tasklist";
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\PsExec.exe";
psi.Arguments = executeCommand;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
Console.WriteLine("File [" + psi.FileName + "] - Args [" + psi.Arguments + "]");
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = psi;
p.Start();
StreamReader outputReader = p.StandardOutput;
StreamReader errorReader = p.StandardError;
p.WaitForExit();
```

i don't get any answer after ten minutes waiting. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you have output buffer full and waiting to be emptied. There are number of common issues people run into when using `Process`. Here is a quick tour with some code samples http://csharptest.net/321/how-to-use-systemdiagnosticsprocess-correctly/